# Abstract Base Class, private inheritance and multiple public inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract, multiple-inheritance

I have an issue or a misunderstanding. Here I have some ABC (`Person`) also two privately derived virtual classes (`PokerPlayer` and `Gunslinger`). To this part everything works perfect until I have to declare a public class (`BadDude`) derived from (`PokerPlayer` and `Gunslinger`). The problems is  =>.

1)

```
 BadDude::BadDude(const BadDude & obj) 
: Person::Person(obj) /*<- the problem*/, PokerPlayer(obj) , Gunslinger(obj) {}
```

---

2)
This happens also with `operator=();`.

```
BadDude & BadDude::operator=(const BadDude & obj)
{
    if (this == & obj)
        return *this;

    Person::operator=(obj); //dose not work
    PokerPlayer::oprtr(obj);
    Gunslinger::oprtr(obj);

    return *this;
}
```

3)
I cant reach protected ABC's method from BadDude's method

```
void BadDude::Show()const
{
    Person::Data(); //the same problem
    Gunslinger::Data();
    PokerPlayer::Data();
}
```

This is what studio says to problem  #1

```
error C2436: '{ctor}' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
```

This is what studio says to problem  #2

```
 error C2249: 'Person::operator =' 
: no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'Gunslinger'
```

This is what studio says to problem #3

```
error C2249: 'Person::Data' : no accessible path to private member declared in virtual base 'Gunslinger'
```

Here the code [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/4h5ymNXQ)

Comment: 1) You have extra `Person::` in your `BadDude` constructor.

Comment: Why (virtual) inherit privately from `Person` ?

Comment: @MikhailGritsenko There's only one `Person::` - you can't miss it.

Comment: well, sure if public everything will work fine. but I have to solve this problem with private inheritance. I`m doing exercises from Prata c++ 11

Answer (score 0):

For problem 1: there is extra `Person::`, it should be

```
BadDude::BadDude(const BadDude & obj) : Person(obj), PokerPlayer(obj) , Gunslinger(obj) {}
```

For problem of accessibility, use protected (or public) inheritance:

```
class Gunslinger : virtual protected Person
{ /*...*/ };
class PokerPlayer : virtual protected Person
{ /*...*/ };
```

Comment: derived class has one base class (Person) and two virtually derived  classes which derived from Person. As I know a multiple derived class from virtual classes which derived from base class have one base class and it means I have to call base class constructor from the last derived class